# Azure File Share Usage throws Int32 error

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-storage

I get 'Exception calling "GetStats" with "0" argument(s): Value was either too large or too small for an Int32' error while using below code.

I have already tried to convert it into Int64 using Toint64() but I still face the same error.All I could find is below link but I don't know how to implement it.

https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/file/ShareStats.html#getUsage()

'''$fileshare = Get-AzStorageShare -Context $context

$fileshare.GetStats().UsageInBytes'''

Please help to get usage of azure file share. It will also be very helpful if someone can explain how can I use method mentioned in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same issue of https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6af9db57-b45e-4967-ab88-e009a6762ea9/azure-file-share-powershell-getstats-throws-int32-error?forum=windowsazuredata, which I have already answered.

The error is from “Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File” library (Powershell based on it).
I have ping the related feature team to fix the library, and PSH will get fixed by upgrade to the fixed library.

Comment: Yes I saw that on the forum. Can you help me to use sharestats() instead of getstats(). I can't find sharestats() in my Az module. I have shared the link in question for the same.